# Обычный код с canvas грузит процессор на 100%

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, canvas

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas">Ваш бразуер не поддерживает Canvas.</canvas>
        <script>
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Грузит процессор на 40-100% (видно в Hot Tabs Killer в опере), хотя код очень простой и должен нормально работать.

Comment: А если так написать `<script type="text/javascript">`, что-нибудь поменяется? Еще я бы добавил `<meta charset="utf-8">` в `head`.

Comment: @aepot ничего не поменялось.

Comment: Это только в Опере воспроизводится, или во всех браузерах? Какая версия и тип браузера? Десктоп или мобильный? Дополните вопрос этими данными.

Comment: И убедитесь, что у вас не стоит никаких лишних браузерных расширений, которые тоже могут грузить процессор. Проверьте проблему в чистом браузере без расширений и прочего мусора